# Sort and count words in xml output python script

Tags: xml, api, count, python-2.6, ietf-restconf

I'm trying to sort and count every word from the output of the `i.find().text` command, but I can't find a way to do it without hardcoded filter words in the array.

Used strings:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 

root = ET.fromstring(response.text)

data = root.findall('file.xml')

for i in data:
   print(i.find('file.xml/ssidname').text)
```

The output of string:

```
SSID1
SSID1
SSID1
SSID2
SSID3
SSID1
SSID3
SSID2
SSID2
```

The excepted answer is:

```
SSID1: 4, SSID2: 3, SSID3: 2
```

I'm stuck on `python 2.6.6` and can't update it, so the idea of using counters can't be used.

If you have any tips, please let me know in the comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know which parts actually work in Python 2.6 but here is a probable solution:

```py
text = '''SSID1
SSID1
SSID1
SSID2
SSID3
SSID1
SSID3
SSID2
SSID2'''


counter = {}
for line in text.split('\n'):
    counter[line] = counter.get(line, 0) + 1

final = dict(sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
print(final)
```

Comment: It works perfect with hardcoded text, but I'm taking my output from cisco restconf API. And '''final''' count and print just first printed string in there. Output is : {'SSID1': 1}. Do you maybe know how to let him read all output of '''*.find('www.cisco.com/restconf.xlm').text'''?

Comment: @jamreg could you provide a sample of that that also has some general characteristics of how usually the text is given or basically some other sample, I could imagine that using `re` module (if that exists in Python 2.6) would be possible

Comment: @jamreg no, only here, but you can edit your question to add the additional data, also how exactly are you supposed to count them? words, specific words, lines?

Comment: no problem, everything is fine here too. I edited my question and read about the ``` re ``` module, but probably my python level is not yet good enough to understand how to combine it in my situation.

Comment: @jamreg move the `counter = {}` out of the for loop, otherwise it is redefined each iteration, also move the `final` stuff out of the loop too

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend.